# UIPageControl and VoiceOver/accessibility

Tags: ios, accessibility, uipagecontrol

When using voice over on the springboard, when the UIPageControl at the bottom of the screen is selected, VoiceOver announces something like "Page 1 of 5.  Adjustable." and the user can swipe up and down to change pages.

In my app, I do not get the "Adjustable" part, and the pages cannot be changed by swiping.

Any ideas how I fix this?  It obviously kills the usability of the app.

Comment: Are you doing this in InterfaceBuilder or programatically? It sounds like it's missing the trait [UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustible](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAccessibilityAction_Protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html) — are you using the Page Control directly or inside another view that knows how to manage it?)

Answer (score 8):

I have subclassed `UIPageControl` and overrode the `-accessibilityTraits` getter to return `UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable` getting Voice Over to read "adjustable".

To add actions: implement the `-accessibilityIncrement` and `-accessibilityDecrement` methods specified in the `UIAccessibilityAction` category.

Since my pages respond to the `UIControlEventValueChanged` events, I make sure to send actions for this event too.

Sample code

```
@interface AccessibleUIPageControl : UIPageControl

@end

@implementation AccessibleUIPageControl

- (UIAccessibilityTraits)accessibilityTraits
{
    return super.accessibilityTraits | UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable;
}

- (void)accessibilityIncrement
{
    self.currentPage = self.currentPage + 1;
    [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

- (void)accessibilityDecrement
{
    self.currentPage = self.currentPage - 1;
    [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

@end
```

Comment: Usually, you [combine the traits](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccessibility_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSObject/accessibilityTraits) from `super` with the desired traits, like `return super.accessibilityTraits | UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable`.

Answer (score 5):

**If you're supporting iOS 9 and newer, this behavior is now the standard - no special handling required.**

If you're supporting iOS 8 and lower, subclass `UIPageControl` and override `accessibilityIncrement` and `accessibilityDecrement`. You don't need to override the `accessibilityTraits` property to indicate it's adjustable - `UIPageControl` is adjustable by default.

```
import UIKit

class AccessibleUIPageControl: UIPageControl {

    override func accessibilityIncrement() {
        self.currentPage += 1
        self.sendActionsForControlEvents(.ValueChanged)
    }

    override func accessibilityDecrement() {
        self.currentPage -= 1
        self.sendActionsForControlEvents(.ValueChanged)
    }

}
```

Then in your view controller you can listen for ValueChanged and respond appropriately to show the content for the new page:

```
//viewDidLoad:
self.pageControl.addTarget(self, action: "didChangePage", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

func didChangePage() {
    let contentOffset: CGFloat = collectionView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(pageControl.currentPage)
    collectionView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(contentOffset, 0), animated: false)
}
```

Note that if you don't subclass `UIPageControl` this target/action will still be called but the current page dot indicator will not update.

Comment: Hi, the issue I'm having with page control is that I'm unable to get it to increment or decrement the counter when the focus is on it. I'm targeting platforms iOS 10 and above. Any way to help me out? Thanks!

Comment: @KarthikKannan Sorry I haven't seen that issue myself

Answer (score -1):

I still needed to implement the Custom AccessiblePageControl using iOS 10+ (as suggested above). I followed the approach above but linked an IBAction on my storyboard for both touchUpInside and valueChanged.